# Redirect New Joomla Install on Different Server

Tags: mod-rewrite, joomla

I made a backup of an existing Joomla website hosted on Siteground at [Globalcoachcenter.com](http://www.globalcoachcenter.com/) using the Akeeba backup and the kickstart extension.

I uploaded the `.jpa` file via FTP to a sub-directory on my Go Daddy server and setup a new subdomain `assessment.globalcoachcenter.com` to access it so I can make changes.

I extracted all of the files using the `kickstart.php` file, but on the Akeeba **'Restoration and Clean Up'** page when I click **'View your site's frontend'** it takes me back to the original Joomla installation on the Siteground account. In other words, it goes to `Globalcoachcenter.com` instead of `assessment.globalcoachcenter.com`. When I click '**'View your site's backend'** I get a nice note from my ISP saying the website cannot be found.

**What I've done / tried:**

- Exported the SQL database from the original Joomla install on Siteground and uploaded it into a new DB on Go Daddy.
- Updated the `configuration.php` file with the new DB name, DB user and DB password and also made sure that the `$log_path` and `$tmp_path` are pointing to my sub-directory.
- Updated the `$live_site` to: `var $live_site = 'http://assessment.globalcoachcenter.com';`
- I discovered a `modrewrite` in the `.htaccess` file but I'm not very good with rewrites - see full rewrite below.

**Here's the .htaccess Rewrite:**

```
##### Automatic compression of resources -- END
##### Redirect index.php to / -- BEGIN
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !^POST
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /index\.php\ HTTP/
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT}>s ^(443>(s)|[0-9]+>s)$
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ http%2://www.globalcoachcenter.com/ [R,L]
##### Redirect index.php to / -- END
##### Redirect non-www to www -- BEGIN
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R,L]
##### Redirect non-www to www -- END
```

Can anyone help? Am I missing another step?

I'm very new to Joomla, please let me know if I need to post more info, I'd be happy to.

Thanks very much in advance.

**Update**:

[**Link to Updated .htaccess file**](https://jsfiddle.net/SteveDillon/5vLyv3na/)

[**Link to .htaccess.admintools file**](https://jsfiddle.net/SteveDillon/41ady0wj/)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your subdomain is setup correctly in cPanel.  It should be pointing to the subfolder that the new cloned site is in. So if the files for Globalcoachcenter.com are in the **/public_html/** folder and the subdomain is in a folder named **/assessment/**, then ensure the subdomain is pointing to **/public_html/assessment/**.  That should make sure the subdomain goes to the right home page.

To have search engine friendly links work, you would set the Rewrite Base in the .htaccess right under the RewriteEngine On at the top:

```html
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /assessment
```

In both examples, adjust the folder name to the correct one.  Also, remove the rewrite you added.

I would drop the $live_site and leave it blank as some 3rd party extensions have issues with it.  If that doesn't answer your question exactly, please comment and I can edit comment.

**EDIT:**

- For testing purposes, I would remove the AdminTools .htaccess till you get the site working.
- You need to remove the extra RewriteBase / in your .htaccess.  The file renders from top to bottom and will override the previous.
- Please comment out the **Options All -Indexes**

Comment: Thanks very much! I confirmed the subdomain is pointed to the correct sub-folder and made the changes to `.htaccess` and `configuration.php` you suggested, however, now [http://assessment.globalcoachcenter.com](http://assessment.globalcoachcenter.com/) now just hangs and then attempts to `download` a file? I also tried accessing the `administrator` backend and it can't be found. Any thoughts? Thanks again for your help

Comment: On your .htaccess, find the lines that start with Options (+Indexes, FollowSysLinks, etc).  Whether those are needed vary from host to host.  Tinker with commenting/uncommenting.  Might check how it is setup in globalcoachcenter.com site if that is working.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I guess now I'm confused. When I copied over the existing site using FTP there were two .htaccess files that came with it. `.htaccess` and `.htaccess.admintools`. I've added links to both of them in my original post with a jsfiddle. I've tried adding the subdirectory path on the `.htaccess.admintools` but the URL still initiates a download.